# Automatically install a desktop launcher for an Ubuntu .deb package

Tags: ubuntu, packages

I am currently packaging an application in a Ubuntu .deb file. The package will not be distributed publicly.

Currently, I package a .desktop file which is installed to `/usr/share/applications`. After installing the package, the .desktop file gets picked up correctly, and a new entry for my application is added to the Applications menu. So far, so good.

Besides the Applications menu entry however, I also want to install an application launcher on the user's desktop. The problem is that I do not know beforehand the directory of the user's Desktop. How should I install a launcher on the user's desktop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119031/how-to-set-my-applications-desktop-icon-for-linux-kde-gnome-etc

EDIT: see comments for info on using xdg-desktop-icon command in postinst/postrm scripts.

Comment: I already have a .desktop file, the challenge is how to get it installed on the user's desktop. I'm not using Cmake, I'm using Ubuntu's packaging tools, dh_make and debuild.

Comment: I don't know if there is a better way, but you can install it calling xdg-desktop-icon install .../program.desktop from the post installation script debian/postinst, and remove it calling xdg-desktop-icon uninstall ... from the post removal script debian/postrm

Comment: I have tried Using `xdg-desktop-icon install`. The desktop icon is installed to the user's desktop, but is read-only for root. How to ensure that the desktop icon is usable by the user?

Comment: The environment variables $SUDO_USER and $HOME (I believe that both are present on postinst) are useful to do this, they both refer to the user that executed the installer. After installing the file, you can change its file ownership to $SUDO_USER and file permissions to 755.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work using the `$SUDO_USER` environment variable. For some reason, `xdg-desktop-icon` insisted on installing the .desktop file to `/root/Desktop` all of a sudden. I copy the .desktop file manually now to the Desktop of `$SUDO_USER`, and adjust its permissions accordingly.

Comment: xdg-desktop-icon's man page says it installs the file to the desktop of the current user, which is root on postinst and postrm.

Comment: postinst: `su - $SUDO_USER -c "xdg-desktop-icon install /path/to/your/program.desktop"`. For prerem, use the same thing, but "uninstall"

Comment: That's precisely why it is a ***bad*** idea to install shortcuts in the desktop at install time. Install is run by root, it should never touch user files.